# How to pass text features to a scikit-learn classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, svm, text-classification

I'm in a sentiment analisys task, right now i have extracted some linguistic features or bigrams (the ocurrence of noun/adjective). At some point of this task i'll need to use scikit to classify this opinions, how can i pass this bigrams, trigrams, ngrams to an implementation of the SVM's algorithm in scikit learn?.

Comment: How does the data exist now? The most natural way is to make a feature matrix where rows are the text elements you're trying to classify and the columns are the ngrams.

Comment: I currently have the text data as a .txt file and POS tagged representation. Also i create a procedure that extracts tuples of Noun/adjective words and other time ocurrence POS features, here is an output of that procedure: `[('carga', 'NCFS000', 'superior', 'AQ0CS0'), ('carga', 'NCFS000', 'frontal', 'AQ0CS0')]`

Comment: Check out the feature extraction tools in scikit-learn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html